# IOS/Objective-C: Set property in presenting view controller

Tags: ios, uipresentingcontroller

When you create a modal View Controller using code, the modal controller has the ability to access the presenting controller.

Please read following.  This is the crux of question.  I do not want to use delegates.

According to [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller)s:

When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or implicitly) using the present(_:animated:completion:) method, the view controller that was presented has this property set to the view controller that presented it.

I want to set the value of a property of the presenting view controller.  However, I don't create the VC in code.  I use a segue from a button.

This gives error: Property afterAdd not found on object of type UIViewController:

```
   self.presentingViewController.afterAdd = YES;
```

where the property afterAdd is set as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL afterAdd;
```

Is there any way to set the value of a property in the presenting view controller when the link is by storyboard that is analogous to the above and does not involve using delegate methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Those answers ignore presentingViewController which is the essence of my question.

Comment: I understand. But the mentioned post describes the best practices. Your code relates to `presentingViewController` which can be different after refactoring or when you change your navigation flow. I recommend you to use one the technique described in the post marked as duplicate. Anyway, I post the answer for your problem below.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast `self.presentingViewController` to your real view controlller class. Something like this, just replace `MyCustomViewController` with your real controller name: `((MyCustomViewController *)self.presentingViewController).afterAdd = YES;`.

Comment: Also, if you use `segue` for presentation, you can setup your controller in `prepareForSegue:sender` function. More information can be found there [Using Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html).

Comment: This makes sense but is giving error "Expected Expression".

Comment: Never mind, I had typo.  Extraneous character.  This worked.  Thanks.

Comment: There was a typo.  But after fixing it, it tries to find the property on the TabViewController in which the presenting controller is embedded.

Comment: Try to use [.selectedViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller) on your tab bar, like `((MyCustomViewController *)((UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController)).afterAdd = YES;`, but as I told you early - this is the bad practice, I'm sure there will be more problems. I still recommend you to try `prepareForSegue:sender` technique.

Comment: I know how to use prepareForSegue to pass data forward.  But I don't know how to use it to get the data back from the desintationViewController.  Basically when the destinationVC is ready to dismiss itself after doing a save, I want it to change a value back in the presentingView Controller to prevent something from happening.  The delegate approach just seems very complicated and therefore fragile.

Comment: How would I add selectedVC to the mix?  ((myVC *)((UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController.selectedViewController.afterAdd does not work.  Alternatively, could I do something with myVC * rootViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];

Comment: The idea is to retrieve your view controller from hierarchy and call the method you want, but I cannot help in this situation, because I need to know your's view hierarchy to propose a valid option.
If you want to pass data back, you should use unwind segues ([Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)). With unwind segue you can handle dismissing of your destination view controller in presenting view controller.